# jquery get character limit?

Tags: javascript, php, json, xampp

I have a code like this.

```
$.get("url")
        .done(function(data){
            alert("success");
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            alert("fail");
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

When I make the url return 95 elements, it goes into done, alerts success, and alerts the contents of the array. But if I make it return an array greater than 95, it goes into fail but still prints the contents of the array correctly.

I used Chrome's DHC - REST/HTTP API Client app to test it out also. When I make the url return 95 elements everything is good. If I make it return 96 elements, it still shows all the elements inside the array but says 'Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 8430.' at the top.

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Googling didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: So the issue is with the server?

Comment: can you give instances of url?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's with the server. 

url is like this : http://localhost/api/points

Comment: well fail has the arguments of `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown` so log them.

Comment: Oh didn't know about that. Just tried and got SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected '}'. I have '}' missing at the end, which is weird because it's not missing for small array but it is for big array. Anyway at least know which direction I have to go from here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. GET indeed had a character limit. I had to use POST instead.